# return the end of process with subprocess in Python

Tags: python, docker, subprocess

I'm using subprocess (Python 2.7) to call a process on a software container (Docker). This process creates some files in a directory. I need that when the process ends and the files are created the function F returns a boolean value so that I know that I can access those files. How can I do this?

```
def F():
    cmd1 = 'my_command_that_invoke_docker'
    process = subprocess.Popen(cmd1, shell=True)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can wait for the child process to terminate.

If you want the STDOUT and/or STDERR streams from the subprocess (and/or send data to process' STDIN), use `process.communicate` method:

```
stdout, stderr = process.communicate()
```

`process.returncode` will have the exit status.

On the other hand, if you just need to wait for the process termination, without any stream capturing, use `process.wait` method:

```
returncode = process.wait()
```

`returncode` will contain the exit status of the subprocess.

** Note that, in case of `shell=True`, the subprocess would be shell itself (unless you `exec` any command directly).

Comment: I've upvoted you, but I don't have a reputation high enough to make it visible!